# Creating a mirror reflection that appears to move faster than light

Tags: optics, reflection, relativity

In the wikipedia article about tachyons, there is a visualization of what would see if such a particle exists and can interact with light and become visible.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon

Obviously we cannot force an object to move faster than light. However, a mirror can make objects **appear** to move faster than they really are. When you look at a stationary mirror, you see your own reflection standing still. If the mirror moves towards you, you see your reflection move towards you at **twice** the mirror speed.

Now you see that if the mirror moves at slightly over half the speed of light, the reflection *should* appear to move just over the speed of light. For example, moving at just 60% the speed of light, the reflection should move at 120% (or 20% higher than) the speed of light.

Given that:

1- the mirror moves towards you head-on, meaning it moves towards your location and is positioned perpendicular to its moving direction.

2- the mirror has two reflective sides, so that you can later see the opposite effect, when the mirror moves away and leaves you behind

3- the mirror moves at a constant speed, over 50% the speed of light

4- all the questions will be regarding the reflection, not the mirror

The question: how would the reflection look like when the mirror moves towards you and then away from you? Will the doppler effect be affected by the mirror's speed instead of the apparent reflection's speed?

Comment: Those are all good questions ( too many, perhaps, for one SE question.  But think about these things: How will the speed of the mirror toward you affect the angle at which a ray is reflected, given the finite speed of light? How will the wavelength of the light be affected?  How long does it take for a change in orientation of the mirror to be apparent if you're, say, a kilometer in front of the mirrpr?

Comment: " If the mirror moves towards you, you see your reflection move towards you at twice the mirror speed." I do not think this is correct. Can you please explain why this would be the case?

Comment: @Arpad the **perceived** distance from you to your reflection is twice the distance from you to the mirror. As the mirror approaches to you, your **image** appears to come closer to the mirror while the mirror approaches you. In other words, it catches-up with the mirror. For all purpose of photography, for instance, the reflection has depth. Itcan be dealt with like the real thing, including focusing, zooming and flash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special Relativity & Mirror Reflection](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43591).

Answer (score 2):

The mirror image will move towards or away from you at a speed larger than c, but this will not look any weirder than seeing a movie in fast motion in which things might look like moving at speeds larger than $c$, because they are not real objects and they cannot transmit information. The Doppler effect will be that of a moving mirror (see [here](https://arxiv.org/ftp/physics/papers/0409/0409014.pdf)), rather than that of the moving image. The apparent speed of light when the mirror is approaching will be $c+v$ if your image (or rather you) send a light beam towards you.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct! Photons are not emitted from the virtual image positioned behind the mirror, but rather from the surface of the mirror.